# How to write the Pivot clause for this specific table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2014. Below is an extract of my table (t1):

```
Name    RoomType    Los   RO   BB     HB    FB   StartDate    EndDate     CaptureDate
A         DLX        7    0    0     154   200  2022-01-01   2022-01-07  2021-12-31
B         SUP        7    110  0       0     0  2022-01-01   2022-01-07  2021-12-31
C         COS        7    0    0     200   139  2022-01-01   2022-01-07  2021-12-31
D         STD        7    0    75      0   500  2022-01-01   2022-01-07  2021-12-31
```

I need a Pivot query to convert the above table into the following output:

```
Name    RoomType     Los   MealPlan   Price     StartDate    EndDate     CaptureDate
 A        DLX         7      RO         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31 
 A        DLX         7      BB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 A        DLX         7      HB         154     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 A        DLX         7      FB         200     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 B        SUP         7      RO         110     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31 
 B        SUP         7      BB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 B        SUP         7      HB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 B        SUP         7      FB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 C        COS         7      RO         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31 
 C        COS         7      BB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 C        COS         7      HB         200     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 C        COS         7      FB         139     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 D        STD         7      RO         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31 
 D        STD         7      BB         75      2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 D        STD         7      HB         0       2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
 D        STD         7      FB         500     2022-01-01   2022-01-07   2021-12-31
```

I had a look at the following article but it does not seem to address my problem:

[SQL Server Pivot Clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php)

I am did some further research but I did not land on any site that provided a solution to this problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want an `UNPIVOT` here ([comparison docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)).

```
SELECT Name, RoomType, Los, MealPlan, Price, 
       StartDate, EndDate, CaptureDate
FROM dbo.t1
UNPIVOT (Price FOR MealPlan IN ([RO],[BB],[HB],[FB])) AS u;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d0c8ee4e4277bf3ec579030504c7334)